# How to group entities using many-to-many relationship

Tags: .net, nhibernate, many-to-many, grouping, relationship

I have the following entity `Book`, where I want to group books (each book in the `BookSeries` should reference all other books in the series). I expect my class will have the definition as follows:

```
public class Book {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Book> BookSeries { get; set; }
}
```

I expect the NHibernate mapping will be as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="Model" assembly="Model">
<class name="Book" table="Books" lazy="false">
    <id name="Id" column="Id" type="int" unsaved-value="">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <bag name="BookSeries" table="BookSeries">
        <key column="Id"/>
        <many-to-many class="Book" column="BookSeriesId" />
    </bag>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Now, I have the follwing 3 questions:

1. What is the best way to model this kind of relationship (self-referencing)?
2. How should this be mapped using NHibernate?
3. When inserting new books in the BookSeries, how to make sure, that the new book references all books in the series (and vice versa)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping seems right to me. Have you tested it? I have a similar working example and it's exactly as you did with the collection. So in my opinion,

Q1: Seems to be a good way to do it.

Q2: It could be mapped the way you did.

Q3: When you insert a new book with the BookSeriesID and then you load a book with that BookSeriesID, the recently inserted book will be loaded automatically provided that it matches the condition for the ID.

Hope that helps, 
Thanks